# CSS Grid - Make table-like grid overflow when item is too big

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a table with CSS grid. So far I created a simple outline.

I have to create the grids at the `row` level (due to the fact that IRL the tables have more elements and I cannot make them at the `table` level). So far this works unless there is a very long word (or number), as in that case it overflows the containing cell.

My question is: **is it possible to make the table overflow in order to make the cells at least as big as the biggest single word or number? (without making them break—at least the numbers)**

Thanks in advance!

*Edit: I need to create a table with CSS grid as I need to use the same layout for the mobile version*

*Edit2: I don't know in advance how many elements I will have in the rows/columns, so I need to make use of* `repeat`

*Edit3: I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.*

```css
.table {
  margin: 48px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #cfcfcf;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(72px, 1fr) );
  min-height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  align-items: center;
  
}

.row:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Name</div>
        <div class="column">Age</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Book</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Color</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Meal</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Jimmy</div>
        <div class="column">23</div>
        <div class="column">None</div>
        <div class="column">White</div>
        <div class="column">Paella de Chorizo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Johny</div>
        <div class="column">56</div>
        <div class="column">Finnegans Wake</div>
        <div class="column">Purple, Magenta and Violet</div>
        <div class="column">None</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Robert The Snake Robertson</div>
        <div class="column">1.234.567.890.000.000</div>
        <div class="column">The Count of Monte Cristo</div>
        <div class="column">Orange</div>
        <div class="column">Apples</div>
      </div>
    </div>
        
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: So dumb question, but if its a *table* displaying what looks like *tabular data*, why not use an HTML `<table>`?

Comment: Hi Bryce, the problem is that I want to use this same layout for the responsive/mobile version. And with CSS grid it is fairly simple to do that with a few lines of CSS, but with an old and grumpy html table that would be very hard to achieve at all.

Comment: Totally understand. Just thought I'd save you from reinventing the wheel (er table) if I could :-)

Comment: Responsive tables are kind of a gray area, as there are not very optimal solutions and/or best practices. Best approach I found is this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-nakayama-shingo-creating-responsive-tables-with-pure-css-using-the-grid-layout-module-8e0ea8f03e83/ There is also more alternatives discussed here https://medium.com/appnroll-publication/5-practical-solutions-to-make-responsive-data-tables-ff031c48b122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a table layout, then use table and not grid:

```css
.table {
  margin: 48px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #cfcfcf;
  font-family: Arial;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  min-height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:10px 0;
}


.row:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Name</div>
        <div class="column">Age</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Book</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Color</div>
        <div class="column">Favourite Meal</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Jimmy</div>
        <div class="column">23</div>
        <div class="column">None</div>
        <div class="column">White</div>
        <div class="column">Paella de Chorizo</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Johny</div>
        <div class="column">56</div>
        <div class="column">Finnegans Wake</div>
        <div class="column">Purple, Magenta and Violet</div>
        <div class="column">None</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">Robert The Snake Robertson</div>
        <div class="column">1.234.567.890.000.000</div>
        <div class="column">The Count of Monte Cristo</div>
        <div class="column">Orange</div>
        <div class="column">Apples</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Temaini, I need to create a table with CSS grid as I need to use the same layout for the mobile (responsive) version in a way that is not possible to achieve with display:table

Comment: @Joe82 and what is this *way*? actually the code I provided is given the same output as your code + the requirement you want. How you will manage the responsive later?

Comment: Using what is described here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/https-medium-com-nakayama-shingo-creating-responsive-tables-with-pure-css-using-the-grid-layout-module-8e0ea8f03e83/ (not the wrapping, but the card layout). Take in account as well that my real tables are much "wider"—they have lots of columns.

Comment: @Joe82 as you can see in that code, they are using media query to switch the layout so my code still work fine. You keep display:table for big screen and you switch to display:grid for small screen both are independant. You don't need to exactly follow that tutorial, you simply need to understand the trick

Comment: True that, I was not thinking about making it that way. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use CSS `fit-content(max-width)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)) but I don't know if it can be used in conjunction with `grid repeat()`.

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto, fit-content(300px), fit-content(100px), auto, auto;
  min-height: 48px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

Edit: Inside a repeat(), you can use the `max-content` [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#max-content).

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, max-content));
```

You might need to add your own wrapping rules for some cells though.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I forgot to add that it is an unknown number of columns (so I need to make use of repeat).

Comment: Perhaps `max-content` then?

Comment: It seems like you cannot use `auto-fit` and `max-content` altogether (check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764726/css-grid-auto-fit-with-max-content ). I've added a plunkr with the modified code here https://plnkr.co/edit/ZaIa8U9tdQydK9UOwN7N

Comment: This isn't helpful, but I haven't found anything that lets you have both content-based widths and an unknown number of columns... Are you expecting to get a bunch of long non-breaking strings in your final layout?

Comment: Yep, as it is full of numbers, and if many of the figures are large, there is overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a mix of grid and flexbox. Try with just grid:

**Updated to set the repeat style inline (since the amount of columns may change)**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);/* overridden inline */
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>div {
  padding: 8px 4px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.grid>div.th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(5,1fr);">
  <div class="th">Name</div>
  <div class="th">Age</div>
  <div class="th">Favourite Book</div>
  <div class="th">Favourite Color</div>
  <div class="th">Favourite Meal</div>

  <div>Jimmy</div>
  <div>23</div>
  <div>None</div>
  <div>White</div>
  <div>Paella de Chorizo</div>

  <div>Johny</div>
  <div>56</div>
  <div>Finnegans Wake</div>
  <div>Purple, Magenta and Violet</div>
  <div>None</div>

  <div>Robert The Snake Robertson</div>
  <div>1.234.567.890.000.000</div>
  <div>The Count of Monte Cristo</div>
  <div>Orange</div>
  <div>Apples</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I didn't clarify it before, but I have an unknown number of rows/columns, so I need to make use of repeat but I cannot specify a fixed number of columns.

Comment: @joe82 You must know how many columns there are at _some point_. For example, when rendering the 'data' you can set the `grid-template-columns: repeat([someNumber],1fr)` as inline style. (I've updated my answer accordingly.)

Comment: That could be an approach. The downside is that I would have to set that number kind of manually in each table, which makes it less maintainable than a pure CSS solution. I will wait if there is a pure CSS solution, else will mark this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Only add word-break: break-word; property in column class

```css
    .table {
      margin: 48px 0;
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px #cfcfcf;
      font-family: Arial;
    }

    .row {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(72px, 1fr) );
      min-height: 48px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    }

    .column {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    align-items: center;
    word-break: break-word;
    }
    .row:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="table">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">Name</div>
            <div class="column">Age</div>
            <div class="column">Favourite Book</div>
            <div class="column">Favourite Color</div>
            <div class="column">Favourite Meal</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">Jimmy</div>
            <div class="column">23</div>
            <div class="column">None</div>
            <div class="column">White</div>
            <div class="column">Paella de Chorizo</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">Johny</div>
            <div class="column">56</div>
            <div class="column">Finnegans Wake</div>
            <div class="column">Purple, Magenta and Violet</div>
            <div class="column">None</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column">Robert The Snake Robertson</div>
            <div class="column">1.234.567.890.000.000</div>
            <div class="column">The Count of Monte Cristo</div>
            <div class="column">Orange</div>
            <div class="column">Apples</div>
          </div>
        </div>
            
        
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Hi @Syed, thanks for the input. That is something I have as last resort, as I would prefer the table to overflow with scroll and being able to see the numbers in a single row (as it is easier to compare figures).