# Organize semi-tabular grid so that columns are all the same width based

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have an object with keys and values that I want to represent in a responsive way so that  are always next to each other, but two k/v entries are stacked because of overflow on the horizontal direction, they will be aligned like a table.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59104556/1626866) looks close to what I want, but does not account for the content size. max-content does not work

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764726/css-grid-auto-fit-with-max-content) also touches on it but recommends flex instead, but flex rows are all calculated independently so that rules that out.

Comment: I have a hunch auto-sizing each column with auto-fit/fill could result in a cyclic behavior: widen columns based on content-> cause wrap-> narrow columns based on better-aligned content -> cause unwrap....