# Why is text-size not taken into account by CSS grid when sizing and flowing auto-fit/fill columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

Please see the snippet below. By using a big text size, you can see that it will overflow the columns in small screens. I can't get why... Shouldn't auto-fill/fit algorithms take it into account while sizing columns and make them flow on the following row?

***Please note***: I am *not* looking for font-size auto-scaling here. My problem here is grid columns are not auto sizing and auto flowing accordingly. Also, if you want to understand the issue, you must see the example on small screens.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(84px, 1fr));
  gap: .5em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 29px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="year-archives custom">
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2022" class="active">2022/23</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2021">2021/22</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2020">2020/21</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2019">2019/20</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2018">2018/19</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="Archivio 2017">2017/18</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You set an explicit text-size. Why would you expect it to change based on the width of the page?

Comment: From looking at the behaviour when it grows and shrinks, it's just calculating where it breaks or how many extra columns to add using minimum value of 84px in the grid-template-columns: property.

Comment: Adam, I think you (the only one til now) get the point. How to solve?

Comment: Yep, unfortunately you can't do repeat(auto-fill, minmax(fit-content, 1fr)). Deeply frustrating having had a good 30 minutes looking at this.

Comment: @Adam: I tried too... Can't understand the reason why it should not working..

Comment: I found this answer which basically said intrinsic sizes like fit-content can't be used with auto-fill and auto-fit. Grr! https://stackoverflow.com/a/53725944/12571484

Comment: @Adam: and basically, in this case flexbox should be used instead of grid. Thank you. If you want to add an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm good dude. I'm going to smash some beers to get rid of this grid layout headache. Have a good one

Answer (score -2):

If the idea is to have the word wrap if it doesn't fit, add this property-value pair to your `li a` selector:

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```